# How to block other data in ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, policy, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a project which contains `Company` and `Agency` users.

I have a problem while I'm trying to show their data. For example: the agency can see other agency's data if they change's the value on the web browser searchbar. I want to block that vulnerability but I don't know how to do that.

I will be doing that first time so, thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: can u explain more ? this search bar what dose it call ?
what should it do ?

Comment: do u mean by search bar the URL ? like "http://myapplication.com/companyinfo?id=44"

Comment: yes,exactly im talkin about that. the user can change the id value and can see other user's value, how to block that ?

Comment: you can compare it with the current logged in user if its match the current logged in user id, if its not you assign each company an Guid in sql server database its called uniqueidentifier and you put the guid in the url this way the no one can get the others info

Comment: the final product would be 
for example 
"http://myapplication.com/companyinfo?DE653F58-AB12-43F9-95CD-A7C3A856340A"

and you make a query to get the company by this uniqueidentifier  i suggest to name the column ObjectKey in the database

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,that way is much better then i have in my mind. thanks a lot!

Comment: glad that helped kindly accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I Understood from you in the comments the Term **SearchBar**
you mean by it , the URL place in the browser.

As my best answer would be to add a `Guid` in the Company Model and map it to a `uniqueidentifier` in the **sql server database**, and when the value is inserted you generate a uniqueidentifier for this company.

then you start getting the company by that object key
so that final product will be something like this :

> **http:///companyinfo?id=DE653F58-AB12-43F9-95CD-A7C3A856340A**